# A visual studio solution that does one nmake

Tags: c, visual-studio, nmake

I'm not really a visual studio developer here. Recently, I was pulled out for a much bigger team to quickly configure and compile a C library for a visual studio project. It took a while going through the README for the library, but I figured out that it basically came down to:

1) Open the VC Command Prompt

2) Run nmake on a .mak file

3) That was it, your dll gets spit out.

So I give it over to the guy, and he says "This is fine and all, but what I really want is a visual studio solution and project." I'm not really a visual studio developer though. All I want is one solution where the compile process is "run nmake". But going through documentation seems to imply that nmake is just a command-line tool. I'm sort of a VS noob though. Is this something you can even do?

Comment: Create a DLL project, add the sources, copy the settings from the .mak file into the project settings.

Comment: One other solution, if it is suitable to you, is to create a makefile project (new project > makefile project then copy-paste your makefile). Once you've done that, you can view and edit the project properties in its property page. The NMake project property page will particulary interest you. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To build a VS solution/project, you can use `msbuild`.  See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

Example:

```
MSBuild.exe MyProject.proj /t:rebuild
```